ls -rt | tail -n 1 does not work inside theJCL - piping symbol causing issue
I am facing a very strange problem, this command ls -rt | tail -n 1 works in linux server in the putty, but the same command when I give inside the JCL, for some unknown reason doesn't work.
//SYSUT1 DD *               
cd /piwin/appdata_new/proj/ftpgapi/sftptest/        
ascii                       
pwd                         
ls -ltr | tail -1

This is the JCL error I am facing

FOTS0821 Can't ls: "/piwin/appdata_new/proj/ftpgapi/sftptest/|" not found

If I just give ls -ltr or ls -la, then the JCL runs fine and returns the expected result, but I need this command
ls -ltr | tail -1 

to work.
Please can some one tell me how to make this command work in JCL, I am not sure if some different coding syntax needs to be followed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am trying to retrieve the latest file from the list of files present in the remote server, and this command works good directly in linux server, but inside JCL, it is causing this issue. It seems to consider the pipe symbol also as a file while inside JCL.

The command is being run directly by JCL, not through a shell. So you need to invoke the shell explicitly.
bash -c 'ls -ltr | tail -1'

I'm assuming JCL will interpret the quotes properly. You might need to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Unfortunately this command also did not work inside the JCL, it is throwing error in FOTS0822 Invalid command
